# How to remove artifacts with SQL Server GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate()

Tags: sql, dissolve, union

We'd like to do an effective "real-time dissolve" on an Esri feature class with a SQL GEOMETRY shape where a parcel layer is "dissolved" into products using an attribute (ProductID) of the parcel layer.  The SQL Server UnionAggregate() function allows for this, using a query like this:

```
CREATE VIEW Product
AS
SELECT 
 PPI.ProductID
 ,GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate(PL.SHAPE) as Shape
FROM ParcelProductInfo PPI
JOIN  ParcelLayer PL ON PPI.ParcelID = PL.ParcelID
GROUP BY  PPI.ProductID
```

This creates the desired result, but it has a side-effect where dangling artifacts are rendered in the Product layer where nodes in the parcel polygons may not have been exactly coincident, as shown here:

[image]

where the blue polygons are parcels and the orange polygons are the "dissolved" products.

Esri has a dissolve tool (arcpy.Dissolve_management())that seems to have an implied tolerance between polygon nodes since we don't see the same artifacts with that tool, but it's not a viable "real-time" solution.  However we're hoping to find something that performs a similar function in conjunction with GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate(​).

Any thoughts or ideas out there?

Comment: Many spatial databases have topology support.  I'm not sure if SQL Server does or not, but I would look at creating topology for your layer with tolerance values that are suitable to your use case.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be a perfect result, but you can try to fill in some of the gaps by applying a positive buffer to the shape before it is dissolved and then a negative buffer to the dissolved shape.

```
CREATE VIEW Product
AS
SELECT 
 PPI.ProductID
 ,GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate(PL.SHAPE.STBuffer(1)).STBuffer(-1) as Shape
FROM ParcelProductInfo PPI
JOIN  ParcelLayer PL ON PPI.ParcelID = PL.ParcelID
GROUP BY  PPI.ProductID
```

This will help the different parcels "reach out" to each other.  If that doesn't work then you might try using `STDifference()` or `STIntersection` to capture all of the small gaps and then dissolve those with their nearest neighbor.